# Codeigniter Htaccess didn't work on win 64-bit

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

My .htaccess file that worked in my Windows 32-bit XAMPP did not work when  moving my directory to a 64-bit Windows.

This URL works in my 32-bit windows but not on my 64-bit setup for which I get "object not found":

```
localhost/folder/controller
```

But this URL does work:

```
localhost/folder/index.php/controller
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 10 and XAMPP I use this.

> htdocs > yourprojectname > .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can also try some more htaccess from here

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

> htdocs > yourprojectname > application > config.php

```
// Must set your base_url in config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: still didnt work on my machine, did you use 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @kai1313 Did you name your files correct? Example: `Welcome.php` and then `class Welcome extends CI_Controller {}` **where only the first letter upper case**

Comment: Im sure I do, because its working fine in my 32 bit devices and hosting

Answer (score 0):

please add .htaccess to the root of codeigniter in .htaccess just add this .. and you are good to go..
**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**

Comment: still wont work
im putting the htaccess on, htdocs/folder/
is it win 64bit need something different than 32bit?
Because my setting and everything works fine on my 32bit devices

Comment: you are using 64 bit xampp? there is no 64 bit version is available for windows yet.. please install the 32bit xampp on c drive(bydefault path) and you are good to go..

Comment: Im using the same installer that I used on my 32 bit devices, and placing it on C (default path)